# Scrolling the parent div with respect to the child div horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following HTML code:

```
<div style="height: auto; width: 400px; overflow: hidden;" id= "parent">
   //dynamic content which makes width of the parent to overflow
   <div style= "height: 200; width: 400px; overflow: auto;" id= "child">
   // dynamic content which makes width of the child div to overflow horizontally and vertically
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way, I can scroll the parent div Horizontally while I am scrolling the child div?
Actually, I am trying to freeze the headings(the content of the parent div) and want a scroll for the data (Content of the child div). Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: doesnt that css just do that?

if you wanna scroll horiontally overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden;
would allow that

Comment: yes, CSS does that but it doesn't give me the required result. I want to keep the headers(contents of parent div) and want to have a scroll on the body. Just like the Freeze pane option in the MS Excel

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS `white-space:nowrap` attribute that may work.

An issue you may be running into is that most HTML text will line wrap by default. You may have to use the `<pre>` or `<code>` tags to get the horizontal scrolling inside the parent `div` without line breaks if that is what you are looking for.

Or to get the freeze pane effect your comment says you are looking for, just use a separate div for the header and content panes.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="info"></div>
</div>
```